# How do I set a destination location for Glass?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I am able to get my current location just fine.  I create a map with driving directions and then I want to allow my user to navigate to their destination.

How do I set the location for the user to navigate?  I do not see a way to set location, there are only location.list() and location.get() methods.  I am using Python, below is my attempted code:

```
work = [lat1, lng1]
#home_location = self.mirror_service.locations().set(home)
body = {
    'location': location,
    'html': PAGINATED_HTML % 
    (lat1, lng1, route(home,work), lat1, lng1, distance(home, work)),
    'notification': {'level': 'DEFAULT'},
    'menuItems': [{'action': 'NAVIGATE'},
        {'action': 'READ_ALOUD'},
        {'action': 'DELETE'}],
    'notification': {'level': 'DEFAULT'}

}
# self.mirror_service is initialized in util.auth_required.
self.mirror_service.timeline().insert(body=body).execute()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destination location which will be used by the NAVIGATE menu command is set in the `location` field. Glass can figure out the current location by itself.

See https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline for details.

Comment: Got it! 'location': {
          "kind": "mirror#location",
          "id": 'home',
          "latitude": lat2,
          "longitude": lng2,
          "displayName": 'Home'},